# MPDF Hangs when run on PHP Built-in server

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

I have project that is using mpdf. I have tried to run MPDF with Apache server, it runs fine. But when I tried to run under PHP built in server it hangs and gets to no where. I cannot figure out why.

The code am running is very basic, nothing fancy.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->writeHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

It's the first time I have issues with PHP built in server and didn't find any warning about PDF. Infact, PDF format is listed as one of supported mime type. Am not sure if it is necessary but It is Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: pdf is just a file type. whatever mpdf() is doing itself may not work in php's built-in server. it's not intended to be a 'real' webserver.

Comment: I understand that it's not meant to be real server but wanted to know why it doesn't work and may be fix it or report to PHP if they can add it in coming versions what will be missing